# Modifying the iframe for FCKeditor

Tags: html, css, fckeditor

I'm trying to figure out what file the styling for FCKeditor's WYSIWIG editor is located.

This is a sample WYSIWIG iframe:

```
<iframe id="edit-field-location-0-value___Frame" height="100%" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" src="/sites/all/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=edit-field-location-0-value&Toolbar=Default" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

I want to modify the height, but I just can't seem to find the file, or any documentation on this. Does anyone have any information?

Answer (score 0):

Hah someone is still using the old module/editor (why?) o.O :-)

Considering that the editor is alrrady dead, same with the FCKeditor module for Drupal, I suggest taking the most easy path - altering the FCKeditor module

Find the following line in `fckeditor.module`:

```
// sensible default for small toolbars
$height = intval($element['#rows']) * 14 + 140;
```

and try setting height to any other value. I do not have this module installed, but that would be my first guess.